# Why is Batman almost always paired with two villains?

Tags: comic-adaptation

In every live action Batman movie I remember (other than Burton's first *Batman*), Batman is paired with two villains. Why is this formula used? Is one villain just not dynamic enough for Batman?

Burton Films

- Batman Returns ('93) - Penguin and Catwoman
- Batman Forever ('95) - Two Face and the Riddler
- Batman & Robin ('97) - Mr Freeze and Poison Ivy (Bane is included, but is subordinate to Ivy)

Nolan Films

- Batman Begins ('05) - Scarecrow and Ra's Al Ghul
- The Dark Knight ('08) - The Joker and Two Face
- Dark Knight Rises ('12) - Bane and Talia Al Ghul

Comment: What about the first Burton's movie? I think there was only Joker there.

Comment: @ChanandlerBong Was there? I've never actually seen that one, but the IMDB roll mentions Harvey Dent (Two-face)

Comment: Dent was not a villain in the first *Batman*. The Joker was the only villain (edited). [What about BvS, BTW?]

Comment: Catwoman is, as always, more of an anti-hero rather than a true Batman villain in Batman Returns.

Comment: Right. If we're counting Catwoman, she was also in Dark Knight Rises.

Comment: Batman Forever was Batman vs Toddler, Robin vs Two Face. Doesn't count.

Comment: I don't know of a particular *reason* for the Two Villain Rule, but I have observed that *superhero movies in general* usually turn to crap if they try to include 3 villains.  True for Batman, Spiderman and X-Men franchises, off the top of my head.  One villain is OK.  Two is the limit.  I guess some producers just like to cram in as many as the director will allow?  (And good directors presumably fight back at more than two.)

Comment: *Batman* (1966) featured more than two villains. And if you count the serials *Batman* (1943) and *Batman and Robin* (1949) I believe these each feature a single villain (not counting henchmen).

Comment: Also, of the three films you listed as "Burton films", only *Batman Forever* was directed by Tim Burton.  Credit for the latter atrocities goes to Joel Schumacher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly it's a holdover from the era when he was paired with Robin.

If you think about it, in the Nolan films, it's not Batman against the two foes, it's Batman **and** Morgan Freeman against the two foes.

Also, Catwoman is never strictly a foe, but also shares a strong affinity for the Batman. Two Face is likewise complex.

Although Bane and Scarecrow are initially presented as the primary protagonist, in both cases they are revealed to be henchmen of the Ghuls.

Can't comment on Ivy, but that particular film does seem to include Robin.

---

The stature of the two directors in question may also be factor.  Layering the antagonists raises the complexity of the narrative.  Nolan is known for highly complex work, and Burton is certainly a director who works on multiple levels.

It would be interesting to find out if Nolan recognized this element of Burton, and decided to continue the tradition.

Comment: Schumacher used two villains as well, but has no talent at all for complex narratives. Still, good observation, and you're right that both Schumacher films include Robin